# How do you prevent launched apps from taking focus?

Tags: macos, applications, dock

I often launch large applications that take many seconds to finish launching. I will click their icon in the dock or launch them from the terminal, and go on with my life. Then seconds later when the app is ready it will be brought to the foreground.

Ideally if an app takes more than 2 seconds to launch, it would stay in the background and not steal focus.

Can I somehow prevent launched applications from stealing focus?

Comment: This is very disruptive if you use multiple spaces and either expect the app to open in the space you launched as opposed to the space you inhabit when it’s done with all the work and presents itself to the OS for input. I think there’s no general workaround and better coded apps is the only actual solution. Let’s see what arrives...